# Construct decimal.Decimal from sign, digits and exponent

Tags: python-3.x, decimal

If I already have a `decimal.Decimal`, I can inspect `d.as_tuple().digits` and `d.as_tuple().exponent`.

But if I have the digits and exponent, how can I efficiently construct a decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`Decimal` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal):

> If value is a tuple, it should have three components, a sign (0 for positive or 1 for negative), a tuple of digits, and an integer exponent. For example, `Decimal((0, (1, 4, 1, 4), -3))` returns `Decimal('1.414')`.